# About Tensor of tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I want to change the shape/dimension of tensor.
For example,

```
x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
```

Then I want to get `y = tf.constant([1,1], [2,2], [3,3]).`

How can I get the new `y` transformation?

I have run the code

```
y = tf.map_fn(lambda e : (e, e), x)
```

But error that occured :

```
ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure.
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you declare explicitally the types:

```
y = tf.map_fn(lambda e : (e, e), x, dtype=(tf.float32, tf.float32))
```

Comment: Thanks, I solve this problem.

Comment: You can set this answer as the right one!